# What does this it~to construction mean?

Tags: cleft-constructions

> His aunt and uncle hadn't been able to think of anything else to do
>   with him, but before they'd left, Uncle Vernon had taken Harry aside.
>   
>        "I'm warning you," he had said, putting his
>   large purple face right up close to Harry's, "I'm warning you now, boy
>   -- any funny business, anything at all -- and you'll be in that cupboard from now until Christmas." 
>        "I'm not
>   going to do anything," said Harry, "honestly.. 
>    
>   But Uncle Vernon didn't believe him. No one ever did. 
>  
>        The problem was, strange things often happened around
>   Harry and it was just no good telling the Dursleys he didn't make them
>   happen. 
>        Once, Aunt Petunia, tired of Harry
>   coming back from the barbers looking as though he hadn't been at all,
>   had taken a pair of kitchen scissors and cut his hair so short he was
>   almost bald except for his bangs, which she left "to hide that
>   horrible scar." Dudley had laughed himself silly at Harry, who spent a
>   sleepless night imagining school the next day, where he was already
>   laughed at for his baggy clothes and taped glasses. Next morning,
>   however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had been
>   before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off He had been given a week in his
>   cupboard for this, even though he had tried to explain that he
>   couldn't explain how it had grown back so quickly. 
>     
>   Another time, Aunt Petunia had been trying to force him into a
>   revolting old sweater of Dudley's (brown with orange puff balls) --
>   The harder she tried to pull it over his head, the smaller it seemed
>   to become, until finally it might have fitted a hand puppet, but
>   certainly wouldn't fit Harry. Aunt Petunia had decided it must have
>   shrunk in the wash and, to his great relief, Harry wasn't punished.
>   
>        On the other hand, he'd gotten into terrible
>   trouble for being found on the roof of the school kitchens. Dudley's
>   gang had been chasing him as usual when, as much to Harry's surprise
>   as anyone else's, there he was sitting on the chimney. The Dursleys
>   had received a very angry letter from Harry's headmistress telling
>   them Harry had been climbing school buildings. But all he'd tried to
>   do (as he shouted at Uncle Vernon through the locked door of his
>   cupboard) was jump behind the big trash cans outside the kitchen
>   doors. Harry supposed that the wind must have caught him in mid- jump.
>   
>        But today, nothing was going to go wrong. *It* was
>   even worth being with Dudley and Piers ***to be spending the day
>   somewhere that wasn't school, his cupboard, or Mrs. Figg's
>   cabbage-smelling living room***.  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

It seems like to infinitival phrase is the semantic subject, and *it* is the dummy-it. Or to infinitival seems like the complement for the previous *worth being with Dudley and Piers*, saying its reason. When I select the latter it’s not easy what do I have to refer to for *it* - that's why I upload quite a lot contents. How do I understand the construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

The underlying structure is

> [Value] ***BE worth*** [Cost]
>   [<sub>Value</sub> This book] **is worth** [<sub>Cost</sub> $25].

Both Value and Cost may be represented by non-finite clauses.

> [<sub>Value</sub> Having this book] **is worth** [<sub>Cost</sub> paying $25].
>   [<sub>Value</sub> Spending the day somewhere that wasn't school, his cupboard, or Mrs. Figg's cabbage-smelling living room ] **was worth** [<sub>Cost</sub> being with Dudley and Piers].

JKR has employed an  ***It-cleft*** construction to put the Value piece in the stronger new-information position. In this construction, *BE worth* requires that the following Value piece be expressed as a *to-infinitive*:

> **It *BE* worth** [Cost] **to** [Value].
>   **It is worth** [<sub>Cost</sub> $25] **to** [<sub>Value</sub> have this book].
>   **It was even worth** [<sub>Cost</sub> being with Dudley and Piers] **to** [<sub>Value</sub> be spending the day somewhere that wasn't school, his cupboard, or Mrs. Figg's cabbage-smelling living room].

Answer (score 1):

The "it" here is referring to "being with Dudley and Piers"; the sentence is saying that being somewhere that wasn't school (etc.) was so enticing that it outweighed the negatives of being with Dudley and Piers.